# Ultrafilter closed under negative shift

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Does exists an ultrafilter $ \mathcal U $ over $\mathbb N $ such that for every $A \in \mathcal U$ the set $A-1=\{a-1\in \mathbb N : a\in A \land  a>1 \} $ is also in $\mathcal U $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Exactly one of $2\mathbb N$, $1+2\mathbb N$ must be in $\mathcal U$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible: As $\mathcal U$ is an ultrafilter, either $ A := \{2n+1 \mid n \in \mathbb N \} \in \mathcal U $ or $\mathbb N \setminus A \in U$.

As $\mathbb N \setminus A = A -1$ and converseley $A = \mathbb N \setminus A -1$, we can only have one of them to be in $\mathcal U$ as otherwise their empty intersection would also be a member of $\mathcal U$.